# How to perform different function on the base of different type of segue?

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I hope I would be able to explain my question.
I have a ViewController named **TouristPictureViewController**

```
class TouristPictureViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var picture: UIImageView!
    var userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    var imageURL:String?



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        getProfilePicture(SuccessCompletion: { (Img) in
            self.picture.image = Img
        }) { (error) in
            print(error)
        }
    }



    func getProfilePicture(SuccessCompletion: @escaping (_ image:UIImage) -> (), FailureCompletion: @escaping (_ error:Error) -> ()) {

           let referecne = Storage.storage().reference(withPath: "user/\(userID!)")
           referecne.getData(maxSize: 5 * 1024 * 1024) { (data, error) in

               if let err = error {
                   print(err)
                   FailureCompletion(err)
               }
               else {
                   if let _data = data {
                       let myImage:UIImage! = UIImage(data: _data)
                       SuccessCompletion(myImage)
                   }
               }
           }

       }
}
```

This VC can be called in two different conditions. First, it is being called when User want to see their profile picture and in that case, It is triggered through **Storyboard.instantiateViewController** and then in this VC, ***getProfilePicture*** function is called. Now, this VC is also triggered through segue, and in that case I am passing an Image URL to this VC and hence with that I want to show that particular Image in this VC. Now what condition should I put here so that the ***getProfile*** function should not be executed in viewDidLoad when I approach this VC by performing Segue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check `imageURL`, it's `nil` in the *instantiateViewController* case

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let urlString = imageURL {
        // load image and assign it to self.picture.image
    } else {
        getProfilePicture(SuccessCompletion: { img in
            self.picture.image = img
        }) { error in
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a global boolean variable like **shouldLoadProfile**

in the **TouristPictureViewController**

```
var shouldLoadProfile: bool = false
```

And in the **viewDidLoad()** method, check shouldLoadProfile or not. Also, you need to set true or false into shouldLoadProfile variable before you transition to **TouristPictureViewController**.

```
override func viewDidLoad(){
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if shouldLoadProfile{

        getProfilePicture(SuccessCompletion: { (Img) in
            self.picture.image = Img
        }) { (error) in
            print(error)
        }

    }else{
        //set imageURL into the UIImageView
    }
}
```